# Accessing 192.168.x.x through AJAX in a Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome-extension, cross-domain

Basically, I have an AJAX request like this:

```
$.ajax({ url:     "http://192.168.0.100/",
         success: function(x) { console.log(x); }
       });
```

with the following permissions array defined in `manifest.json` of the extension:

```
"permissions": [
    "notifications",
    "tabs",
    "*.*",
    "192.168.0.100",
    "192.168.0.100/*",
]
```

A request to `192.168.0.100` fails with the following error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.0.100/.
Origin chrome-extension://<hash> is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

What I already did is appending this header in `index.php`:

```
Header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

but to no avail.

What can I do to make AJAX requests to local IPs work in a Chrome extension?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `"http://192.168.0.100/*"` instead of `"192.168.0.100/*"`. The scheme needs to be specified, see [Match Patterns](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/match_patterns.html) for reference.